# How can I create an API directory using the Google App Engine's Service Generator?

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

I've been following the instructions on Google's Doc. ->
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_ios#Java_Compiling_the_client_library_generator_and_generating_your_library

But I cannot get past step 5 (Compiling the client library generator and generating your library)

```
/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceGenerator-btnyogexyyjtgrgbfjqddcedmkls/Build/Products/Debug/ServiceGenerator \ /Users/username/Documents/discoveryFileName.discovery \ --outputDir /API
```

However, I get the error -  "ERROR: An output directory is required".

Any ideas?! I clearly put the output Directory in there.  Would this error occur if the discovery file was not in the correct format?

I've tried many different output directories as well

Please!!

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using `--outputDir /API` -- that is, trying to create the directory right under the root directory in your filesystem.

The example uses, instead, `--outputDir ~/API` -- that ~ sign just before the / means it creates the directory *inside your home directory* (in Unix-like systems).

You may miss permissions required to create directories at the top of your filesystem, while you likely have such permissions within your home directory. Therefore, I would recommend doing exactly what the example suggests -- keeping the ~ (tilde) there, rather than removing it.

Comment: Did you find any of resolving this issue.. I am also facing this same issue.